# Pentaho named parameter error

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I' m using pdi 4.3.0. I' m facing problem with using named parameter.
I have three transformation.
1.Transformation1

```
select name from master..sysdatabases WHERE NAME LIKE '%C%';
```

2.
 Transformation2

```
use ${name}
select id, date from database1;
```

3.
 Transformation 3

```
use ${name}
select item from db2 where id = ${id} and date = ${date};
```

Now i used job to execute these transformation.

always error comes on T3
**Unknown column 'name'**

Comment: In Transformation1, do you flow the "name" value into a `Set Variables` step?

Comment: thanks @Brian.D.Myers yes , i used copy row to result in transformation 1 and define parameter in both second and third transformation and also in job.but also error

Comment: You're using a "LIKE" clause in Transformation1. Apparently it's possible for (database) name to result in more than one value. Is this correct? The "row results" in PDI is different than Job variables. Row results can have many values; Job variables can have only 1. If there are several databases you're doing this with, you'll need to take a different approach.

Comment: @Brian.D.Myers yes i'm using for two different databases

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use "use" to choose the database name.  That would generally come from the schema in the connection.  In the connection you can use a variable, so does it work if you do it in there?  In fact i'm surprised you can parameterise in that way - some things in jdbc are not parameterisable!

Also check the differences between T2 and T3. Does one have it defined in the transformation parameters tab, and not the other?

Or check how you're calling the transformations. If it works in one and not the other there must be some difference, maybe you're passing the variable down with one and not the other.

Comment: thanks @Codek, the "use" works well if T1 and T2 only.I also used `${name}.dbo.dbname` but also error.Need to transform 2 database

Comment: ok cool - well at least if you have it working in some cases, you know it does work. so you need to just work out what the difference is.

Comment: i think bug or something because variable error when using more than 2 transformation.